# StepBuilder.chunk() returning null with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch configuration class MyConfig with my reader, writer, step and Job beans. Below is my Step bean.

```
@Bean
public Step myStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_NAME).<MyType, MyType>chunk(getMinimumChunkSize())
            .reader(myReader)
            .writer(myWriter)
            .build();

}
```

When I try unit testing it with the below class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
                StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
public class MyConfigTest {

    @Mock
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Mock
    private StepBuilder stepBuilder;

    @Mock
    private SimpleStepBuilder simpleStepBuilder;

    @Mock
    FlatFileItemWriter myWriter;

    @Mock
    JdbcCursorItemReader myReader;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyConfig myConfig;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(stepBuilderFactory.get(anyString())).thenReturn(stepBuilder);
        when(stepBuilder.chunk(any())).thenReturn(simpleStepBuilder);
        when(simpleStepBuilder.reader(myReader)).thenReturn(simpleStepBuilder);
        when(simpleStepBuilder.writer(myWriter)).thenReturn(simpleStepBuilder);
    }

    @Test
    public void testChecklistStep() {
        final Step step = myConfig.checklistStep();
        assertNotNull(step);
    }      
}
```

On debug I get `stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_NAME)` gives the mock as expected shown below

[image]

but the `stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_NAME).<MyType, MyType>chunk(getMinimumChunkSize())` is returning null instead of SimpleStepBuilder mock. This looks pretty straight forward, I am new to mockito and spring batch. Why is the thenReturn not working in this case?

I tried reading [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/testing.html) but this was of less help to what i am trying to do. Please suggest if my approach is wrong or if I'm missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `chunk` method creates a new step builder wrapping your mock: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/StepBuilder.java#L69. So `stepBuilder.chunk(any())` is not the mock you think it is.

That said, I'm wondering why you need to mock `StepBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilder` anyway. Your test is testing that `stepBuilder` correctly creates a Step. Unless you do not trust Spring Batch code, you should not be doing this.

What you should be doing though is testing the actual business logic of your Step (correctly reading/writing data, its processing logic, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand that this is not supposed to be tested, but when I try to test my job execution this piece of code is failing the test. Can you suggest a way around it to complete the answer?

Comment: I am having similar issues with Spring Batch unit testing with Mockito. @Hassine can you provide a coded example of how you would test a reader and mockito the result with the reader actually querying a database?

Comment: I would not mock the reader, I would either use an embedded or containerized db with mock data for tests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216509/5019386.