# How to mock an ItemReader in a Spring Batch application using Spock and Groovy

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spring-batch, spock

I'm trying to write the **tests** for a **Spring Batch** application, specifically on the interaction from the following **reader** when it gets records from a database implementing a simple RowMapper :

```java
@Component
@StepScope
public class RecordItemReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<FooDto> {
  @Autowired
  public RecordItemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.setDataSource(dataSource);
    this.setSql(AN_SQL_QUERY);
    this.setRowMapper(new RecordItemMapper());
  }
}
```

Here is the step definition from the Batch configuration :

```java
  @Bean
  public Step step(RecordItemReader recordItemReader,
                   BatchSkipListener skipListener,
                   RecordItemWriter writer,
                   RecordItemProcessor processor,
                   PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return stepBuilderFactory
      .get("step1")
      .transactionManager(transactionManager)
      .reader(recordItemReader)
      .faultTolerant()
      .skip(ParseException.class)
      .skip(UnexpectedInputException.class)
      .skipPolicy(new AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy())
      .listener(skipListener)
      .processor(processor)
      .writer(writer)
      .build();
  }
```

Everything works fine, except when I try to test using the following :

```java
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class BatchSOTest extends Specification {

  @Resource
  JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils

  @Resource
  JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils

  @Resource
  RecordItemReader recordItemReader

  def cleanup() {
    jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions()
  }

  def "batch init perfectly"() {
    given:
    // this does not work :
    (1.._) * recordItemReader.read() >> null

    when:
    def jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob()
    def jobInstance = jobExecution.getJobInstance()
    def exitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus()

    then:
    jobInstance.getJobName() == "soJob"
    exitStatus.getExitCode() == ExitStatus.SUCCESS.getExitCode()
  }
}
```

I'm not able to Mock the reader properly, I tried various ways like updating reader's properties such as `MaxRows`, but nothing seems to work.

**What is the proper way to update the result of the Reader**?

Or does it needs to be done another way to properly **manipulate the records** from the database **during unit tests**?

---

---

**UPDATE:** Ok so I tried a more structured way using a service inside the reader :

```java
@Component
public class FooDtoItemReader extends AbstractItemStreamItemReader<FooDto> {

  private List<FooDto> foos ;

  private final FooService fooService;

  @Autowired
  public FooDtoItemReader(FooService fooService) {
    this.fooService = fooService;
  }

  @Override
  public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    try {
      foos = fooService.getFoos();
...
```

```java
public interface FooService {
  List<FooDto> getFoos();
}
```

```java
@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

  @Autowired
  private FooDao fooDao;

  @Override
  public List<FooDto> getFoos() {
    return fooDao.getFoos();
  }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public class FooDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements FooDao {

  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;

  @PostConstruct
  private void initialize() {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
  }

  @Override
  public List<FooDto> getFoos() {
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(SELECT_SQL, new FooMapper());
  }

}
```

Here, I'm facing the problem where I cannot mock properly my Service :

I must be missing something with the test utils.

```java
class BatchSOTest extends Specification {

  @Resource
  JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils

  @Resource
  JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils

  FooService       fooService       = Mock(FooService);
  FooDtoItemReader fooDtoItemReader = new FooDtoItemReader(fooService)

  def cleanup() {
    jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions()
  }

  def "batch init perfectly (second version)"() {
    given:
    fooDtoItemReader.open(Mock(ExecutionContext))

    and:
    // still not working from there :
    (1.._) * fooService.getFoos() >> [createFooEntity(123, "Test")]


    when:
    def jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob()
    def jobInstance = jobExecution.getJobInstance()
    def exitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus()

    then:
    jobInstance.getJobName() == "soJob"
    exitStatus.getExitCode() == ExitStatus.SUCCESS.getExitCode()
  }
```

But if I try to mock from there, it works :

```java
class FooDtoItemReaderTest extends Specification {

  FooService fooService = Mock(FooService);
  FooDtoItemReader fooDtoItemReader = new FooDtoItemReader(fooService, 0)

  def "open gets the foos and reader is initialized"() {
    given: "Foos examples"
    def foos = [
      createFooEntity(123, "A"),
      createFooEntity(456, "B")
    ]

    when: "reader is initialized"
    fooDtoItemReader.open(Mock(ExecutionContext))

    then: "service get the expected foos"
    1 * fooService.getFoos() >> foos
  }
```

So what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to testing database interactions, I would not mock the reader. I would instead use an embedded database and populate it with test data. This can be achieved by adding the following bean to your test context:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql")
            .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
            .addScript("/schema.sql")
            .addScript("/test-data.sql")
            .build();
}
```

This example uses H2, but you can use derby or HSLQ or SQLite or any other embeddable database.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I think that is the proper solution.
My reader initially queries 12 tables. I only need to write into 2 tables, so I wrote the JPA entities only for these two. Is it better to write every corresponding entites that can initiate the schema with `jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create` during tests startup OR using a custom sql script ?

Comment: That seems a good idea, but I'm dealing with some Oracle queries, using packages and it does not seem compatible with an embeddable database like H2, as I'm facing a lot of issues.

Comment: In that case, you can use a library like https://www.testcontainers.org to run an oracle db in a container, populate it with test data and run your tests against it.

Comment: That seems the best solution, to stay on the same architectures, but its another heavy work. Right now I'm trying to make a combination works: faking the reader that uses a complex oracle query and using an H2 database for data manipulation as you suggested. I'll update my question based on what is working or not.